# How can I convert from jitter() amounts to position_jitter() widths in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm updating [a package that uses base graphics](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/granova/index.html) to [one that uses ggplot2 graphics](https://github.com/briandk/granovaGG). In the base graphics version, users could supply a value for `jj`, which would then get scaled and passed to a `jitter()` function. The code to jitter x values looked like this:

```
degree.of.jitter <- (jj/200) * diff(x.values.range)
jitter(x.values, amount = degree.of.jitter)
```

I'd like the `ggplot2` version to achieve the same visual jittering effect as the base graphics version. But, I'm not sure how to re-scale my existing `degree.of.jitter` so I can pass it directly to `position_jitter()` and achieve the same visual results:

```
position_jitter(width = MysteriousScalingFunctionOfCompleteMysteryWhoseInnerWorkingsIHaveYetToSpecify(jj))
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for what the appropriate scaling of jj would need to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, `width` is passed as the `amount` argument to `jitter`, so you should be able to just use

```
position_jitter(width = degree.of.jitter)
```

where `degree.of.jitter` is defined the same way as before.

Comment: yep. I also didn't realize that a call to `geom_jitter()` can't just pass a "width" argument directly. It has to pass a `position` parameter that calls `position_jitter(width = degree.of.jitter)`: https://gist.github.com/1152683